# How to use Bootstrap 4 popover dynamically in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have a simple Django app similar to a quiz app. I have stored all the questions with answers in the database. Then, I retrieve all the questions in a template using Django ListView. Each question has 4 options and one answer field. Initially, I want to hide the answer and use a Bootstrap 4 popover. When a user click on the popover button the answer will display. I have done all but the popover is not showing the answer when I click the button. Below is my code -

```
<div class="col-md-12 card border-0 mb-2 mt-3 ml-1">
      <div class="card-body pl-0 pt-3">
        {% for topic in topic_list %}
          <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">{{ topic.name }}</h2>
          
          {% for question in topic.question_set.all %}
            <h6 class="mb-4">{{ question.serial_no }}. {{ question.name }}</h6>
            <div class="form-check ml-3">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">(A) {{ question.option1 | safe }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check ml-3">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">(B) {{ question.option2 | safe }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check ml-3">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">(C) {{ question.option3 | safe }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check ml-3 mb-4">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">(D) {{ question.option4 | safe }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="{{ question.answer }}">
              Show Answer
            </button>      
          {% endfor %}              
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "Popovers are opt-in for performance reasons, so you must initialize them yourself." [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/popovers/). Did you do that?